# "I just sent a mail" or "I just sent mail"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I'm wondering if it is "I have sent a mail to him" Or "I have sent mail to him"

I could not find much online. Thank you.

Comment: It is rather odd that although ***email*** stands for ***electronic mail***, it doesn't obey the same "pluraility" rules as ***mail***. We can use both singular and plural in, say, ***I send email / emails to him***, but only the "singular as uncountable / plural noun" works with ***I send mail to him***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes. "Email" exists both as a countable and uncountable noun, as well as verb and adjective. "Mail" is never countable, though it exists as an uncountable noun, as well as adjective form - in verb form (more often in the US than the UK). We British talk of "posting" a letter.

Answer (score 1):

As some of your initial comments explain, we can say:

> "I've sent **a package** to him, **a letter** to her, **a parcel** to Fred, and **a telegram** to Phil."

I can even say, "I sent **a piece of** mail to him," but, if it's just *mail*, there is no indefinite article:

> I have sent mail to him.

However, for some reason, *email* works with an article (or without, particularly if it's more than one message):

> I sent him an email.

Comment: Even though there is no *indefinite* article used with *mail*, people do send (and deliver) ***the*** *mail*.

Answer (score 0):

"Mail" is an uncountable noun, so you must say, "I have sent him mail," not "I have sent him A mail." It's similar to saying, "I have eaten rice," instead of "I have eaten A rice." As mentioned in the previous answer, if you use the word "letter", then you not only can but must use an article. You would say either, "I have sent him a letter" or "I have sent him the letter" depending on whether your interlocutor were previously aware of the existence of this particular letter.